# Bypassing a custom login page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, security, web

I am demoing a web-application soon and would like to make the flow of my demo a little cleaner.

At the moment, when one clicks on a page, they get redirected to the login for this webpage. I'd like to do away with login page this for my demo.

Let's, as an example, take https://home.bt.com/login/loginform.

I want to add a link to my webpage which will, in the background, log me in as BT ID "User1" with password "securityDoesntMatterForDemos". This can all be hardcoded. The user should only see the webpage navigating them to the members area for this user (whatever page would be produced after an accepted login on this page).

What is the best way of accomplishing this safely and reliably?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to accomplish this would be to have a short and simple webpage that you initially route to that is hosted on your machine. This webpage will use client side code(javascript) to send a request to your server's webservices requesting your authentication token with that username and password, upon receiving it, reroute to your website and hand off the authentication token in the same manner that your login page achieves this, be it in a cookie, local storage, etc etc

This will hide your login credentials from the live version without you having to change how the live version works.